Creating a stream and waiting for data to be ready with async grpc server
Can somebody explain to me how a grpc async server is supposed to keep a stream open while waiting for more data to be ready?
I'd like to block a python client (when it calls the next() to get another element out of the stream) if the data is exhausted and there's nothing else yet (e.g. if it's being produced).
What I've been trying to do is basically this from a python client:
my_service = MyServiceStub(channel)
create_stream_request = MyService.MyServiceCreateStreamRequest()
stream = my_service.CreateStream(create_stream_request) # have a stream object open

# Produce some data and write it on the stream server-side (this code will be called 
# from another part so I need to programmatically tell the server to produce data)
produce_data_request = MyService.MyServiceProduceDataRequest()
my_service.ProduceData(produce_data_request)

# Get produced data out from the stream - BLOCKING IF NOT READY!
new_data = stream.next()
print(new_data)

Here's my complete server code attempt and the part where I'm having issues, I tried using a condition_variable but that hung up the entire grpc handling for subsequent requests. Returning from the Proceed method didn't help either and I got a server crash.

    class StreamingManager {
        StreamingManager(grpc::ServerBuilder& builder) {
            // Builds and start the async service
            builder.RegisterService(&grpcAsyncStreamingService_);
            completionQueue_ = builder.AddCompletionQueue();
            grpcServer_ = builder.BuildAndStart();

            // Start the HandleRpcs function in a separate thread
            std::thread(&StreamingManager::HandleRpcs, this).detach();
        }
         ~StreamingManager() {
            shutdownRequested_ = true;
            grpcServer_->Shutdown(); // Gracefully stop the gRPC server
            completionQueue_->Shutdown(); // Shutdown the completion queue to unblock the thread
        }

        std::unique_ptr<grpc::Server> grpcServer_;
        std::unique_ptr<grpc::ServerCompletionQueue> completionQueue_;
        ::my::proto::MyService::AsyncService grpcAsyncStreamingService_;
        std::atomic<bool> shutdownRequested_;

        // A common base class to keep the requests' status and context together, and also
        // a pointer to the parent class
        enum CallStatus { CREATE, PROCESS, FINISH };
        class CallDataBase {
        protected:
            CallStatus status_ = CREATE;
            grpc::ServerContext serverContext_;
            StreamingManager* streamingService_ = nullptr;
        public:
            virtual void Proceed() = 0;
            virtual ~CallDataBase() {}
        };


        class CallDataProduceData : public CallDataBase {
            protected:
                :::my::proto::MyServiceProduceDataRequest request_;
                :::my::proto::MyServiceProduceDataResponse reply_;                
                grpc::ServerAsyncResponseWriter<decltype(reply_)> responder_; // Note that this is NOT a streaming writer

            public:
                CallDataProduceData(StreamingManager* streamingService) :
                    responder_(&serverContext_) {
                    streamingService_ = streamingService;
                    Proceed();
                }
            public:
                void Proceed() override {
                    if (status_ == CREATE) {
                        status_ = PROCESS;
                        streamingService_->grpcAsyncStreamingService_.RequestCreateStream(&serverContext_, &request_, &responder_,
                            streamingService_->completionQueue_.get(), streamingService_->completionQueue_.get(), this);
                    } else if (status_ == PROCESS) {
                        new CallDataCreateStream(streamingService_);

                        // Start of handling code for produce data
                        // ??? Please read below, not sure how to produce data here because I don't know how to keep
                        // the stream open..
                        

                        status_ = FINISH;
                        responder_.Finish(reply_, ::grpc::Status::OK, this);
                    } else {
                        // We're done! Self-destruct!
                        if (status_ != FINISH) {
                            // Log some error message
                        }
                        delete this;
                    }
                }
            };

            std::condition_variable produceDataCv_;
            std::mutex produceDataMutex_;
            std::atomic<bool> produceDataRequested_;

            class CallDataCreateStream : public CallDataBase {
            protected:
                ::my::proto::MyServiceCreateStreamRequest request_;
                ::my::proto::MyServiceCreateStreamResponse reply_;
                grpc::ServerAsyncWriter<decltype(reply_)> streaming_responder_; // Note that this IS a streaming writer

            public:
                CallDataCreateStream(StreamingManager* streamingService) :
                    streaming_responder_(&serverContext_) {
                    streamingService_ = streamingService;
                    Proceed();
                }
            public:
                void Proceed() override {
                    if (status_ == CREATE) {
                        status_ = PROCESS;
                        streamingService_->grpcAsyncStreamingService_.RequestProduceData(&serverContext_, &request_, &streaming_responder_,
                            streamingService_->completionQueue_.get(), streamingService_->completionQueue_.get(), this);
                    } else if (status_ == PROCESS) {
 
                        new CallDataCreateStream(streamingService_);

                        // Start of handling code for create stream
                        streaming_responder_.SendInitialMetadata(this);
            
                        // PROBLEM IS HERE - HOW TO KEEP THE STREAM OPEN (i.e. not call streaming_responder_.Finish())
                        // BUT WAIT FOR MORE DATA TO BE READY?? A CONDITION VARIABLE HERE PUTS THE THREAD TO SLEEP AND
                        // OTHER "ProduceData()" CALLS WILL NOT BE HANDLED. JUST RETURNING FROM HERE CRASHES WITH AN ASSERT
                        // THAT INITIAL METADATA IS INVALID (and just sending it once at the beginning won't help either, same
                        // crash).
                        while (!streamingService_->m_shutdownRequested) {
                            reply_ = populate_reply_with_random_data();
                            streaming_responder_.Write(reply_, this);

                        }
                    
                        status_ = FINISH;
                        streaming_responder_.Finish(::grpc::Status::OK, this);
                    } else {
                        // We're done! Self-destruct!
                        if (status_ != FINISH) {
                            // Log some error message                            
                        }
                        delete this;
                    }
                }
            };


            void HandleRpcs() {
                // Register the CreateStream and ProduceData handlers
                new CallDataCreateStream(this);
                new CallDataProduceData(this);
            
                void* tag;
                bool ok;
                while (!m_shutdownRequested) {
                    bool ret = completionQueue_->Next(&tag, &ok);
                    if (ok == false || ret == false) {
                        return;
                    }
                    static_cast<CallDataBase*>(tag)->Proceed();
                }
            }

        };

    }

Could somebody please help? I couldn't find any code examples to accomplish the above.
